# java 1D array setting in method

Tags: java, arrays

I want to know if have two arrays testSet and testSet2 of class test1
in method problem() testSet is initialized to 1 and testSet2 is initialized to 0
and after equalizing the testSet2 with testSet the testSet2 lenght become same as of testSet which is fine 
but 
in method problem1() testSet is initialized to 1 and testSet2 is initialized to 0
and after equalizing in method equalize() the testSet2 with testSet the testSet2 lenght become is still 0.
why?

```
public class test1
{
    // C
    public test1(int _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }

    // Field
    public int data;
}

// reference equalize method
public void equalize(test1[] a,test1[] b)
{
    a = b;
}

public test1[] testSet,testSet2; // arrays

// called from main method access
public void Problem()
{    
    // initializing array
    testSet = new test1[1];
    testSet2 = new test1[0];

    testSet [0] = new test1 (11);
    testSet2 = testSet;  

    // testSet2.length = 1 which is fine
}

// called from main method access
public void Problem1()
{  
    testSet = new test1[1];
    testSet2 = new test1[0];

    testSet [0] = new test1 (11);
    equalize (testSet2,testSet);

    // want to know why this is happening ?
    // testSet2.length = 0 
    // in problem() length = 1 but here is 0 why?
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

the reason why the length of testSet2 = 0 was because the method equalize() only use them inside. methods() used the parameters only on their behalf.

if you want to change the length of testSet2. initiate it on the

```
  public TestClass(int _data)
   {
        data = _data;
    testSet2 = new TestClass[0];
}

 and when you want to change it's length try this

 public void Problem1()
{  
testSet = new TestClass[1];
testSet [0] = new TestClass (11);
 equalize (testSet);   

System.out.println(testSet2.length);
System.out.println(testSet.length);



 }

  public void equalize(TestClass[] b)
{
testSet2 = b;
 }
```

Comment: public void equalize(test[] a,test[] b){ b[0].data = 1000} then how b.data[0] sets in other function even if it was locally in equalize function as you said?